# Angular.js: Is it possible to show a AngularStrap modal programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, angular-ui-grid

I want to trigger the AngularStrap modal: `bs-alert` when a has edited a table row in my ng-grid. Depending on the HTTP response status, I want to show different kinds of modal messages, e.g. success and error messages.

My code is that after editing an entry in ng-grid, the following gets triggered:

```
        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function( gridApi ) {
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit( $scope, function( rowEntity, colDef ) {

            $http.put(ApiCall, rowEntity).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                if (data.status === 'OK'){
                    // Trigger Modal bs-alert
                }
                else if (data.status === 'ERR'){
                   // Trigger (same if possible) Modal with different values, coloring, etc
                }
        });
    };
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just pass `'$alert'` into your controller and inside the controller do a

```
var myAlert = $alert({  

    title: 'myTitle',
    content: 'someContent', 
    type: 'success',
    show: true
 });
```

..at the appropiate part of your code and the popup should show. You can also define global properties of the alert in the `app.config` section of your code, passing in `$alertProvider`:

```
angular.extend($alertProvider.defaults, {
            animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-top',
            placement: 'top', 
            duration: 2,
            container: 'header',
            keyboard: 'true',
            show: true,
        });
```